# Execute a command programmatically in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, command-line-arguments, keytool

I want to execute this command in SpringBoot application:

```
keytool -import -keystore trustStore.jks -file certCA.der -storepass example << EOF
\ yes
\ EOF
```

My problem is that I'm not able to insert "yes" automatically in my code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("keytool -import -keystore trustStore.jks -file certCA.der -storepass example");
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-noprompt` argument in your command

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to add -noprompt argument in command but from logs of service it seems that this argument does not trust the trustore (it is as if it answers no to the question in prompt). Infact, I have this exception : Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target